# Loading different Libraries with same Functions dynamically

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a program which has a reference to an external DLL:

```
magic.externalFunctions.sql.dll
```

depending on the target system I might need the following instead:

```
magic.externalFunctions.nosql.dll
```

These DLLs are external libraries who offer the same functionality. Even the public methods and properties are the same. But they **do not** have a combined Interface or base class.

Now I need to chose between these two libraries depending on the target system. If they **would have** an Interface in common I would do something like:

```
public class DoDatabaseStuff() {
    private IMagic _magic
    public DoDatabaseStuff(bool useNoSql) {
       if (useNoSql) {
         _magic=new SqlMagic();
       } else {
         _magic=new NoSqlMagic();
       }
       myTable=_magic.Table.Create("CustomerTable");
       myTable.Columns.Add(typeof(int),"ID");
       myTable.Columns.Add(typeof(string),"Name");
   }
}
```

Is there any way to solve this without using an excessive amount of reflection? I still want to use something like `myTable.Columns.Add()` instead of `tableType.GetMethod("Add").Invoke()...`

I also do not want to use conditions in the csproj using different build configurations. While this does work in theory, it gets distroyed every time the csproj changes automatically(e.g. a nuget-package updates)

Comment: what is the reason for wanting to switch between multiple libraries which do the same thing?  Surely that is an inefficient method AND your increasing the number of dependencies

Comment: But, if you needed to do this, you could always create helper methods, so one calls your SQL library, and one calls the NON SQL library

Comment: We have to deploy our program on two different platforms. Currently we have two projects containing the same source files but different references, but it is a big source for error if the structure changes. We also tried to create two different git-branches as a workaround with the same problems. The main issue here is EXTERNAL libraries. We would have done this a different way if this is our own code.

Comment: Create an assembly that contains base classes or interfaces and only introduce a dependency to this assembly. You can then load the appropriate implementation assembly. Dependecy injection is the way to go in these cases. The main design flaw here is to introduce two separate independent assemblies.

Comment: Helper methods do not really work here. The library is quite complex, the methods itself contain parameters that are of types inside the library like "Magic.Table.Add(Magic.Column column)" so writing helper methods for all of these would end up in basically fixing this for months.

Comment: @Sefe I know it is a design flaw, but not from us, but from the external dll-manufacturer. To be specific it is about SharePoint-2013-DLL vs. SharerPoint-2016-dll vs SharePoint-O365-DLL. And we have to publish our program on all those platforms

Comment: Then you can still introduce an assembly with abstractions and create two adapter assemblies that will reference the abstractions and the respective external libraries. Then you are on common ground again. You can even do everything in one assembly.

Comment: @Sefe is correct, don't perpetuate their design flaw. Abstracting the complexity out is the way to go.

Comment: You don't have to provide helper methods for the entire functionality of the external library. Just for the parts that you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are confronted with bad design that you can not change, a good way to go is to keep that design out of your code. In this case that means that you should create the common interface that your external assemblies are lacking.

You can use adapters to provide a unified interface to keep the initial design flaw out of the core of your code.

You start with creating abstractions for the original classes you want to access:

```
public interface IMagic {
    ITable CreateTable(string name);
}

public interface ITable {
    void AddColumn(Type type, string name);
}
```

Then you provide adapters:

```
class SqlMagicAdapter : IMagic {
    SqlMagic m_innerMagic = new SqlMagic();

    ITable CreateTable(string name) {
        return new SqlTableAdapter(m_innerMagic.Table.Create(name));
    }
}

class SqlTableAdapter : ITable {
    SqlTable m_innerTable;
    public SqlTableAdapter(SqlTable innerTable) {
        m_innerTable = innerTable;
    }
    void AddColumn(Type type, string name) {
        m_innerTable.Columns.Add(type, name);
    }
}

class NoSqlMagicAdapter : IMagic {
    NoSqlMagic m_innerMagic = new NoSqlMagic();

    ITable CreateTable(string name) {
        return new NoSqlTableAdapter(m_innerMagic.Table.Create(name));
    }
}

class NoSqlTableAdapter : ITable {
    NoSqlTable m_innerTable;
    public NoSqlTableAdapter(NoSqlTable innerTable) {
        m_innerTable = innerTable;
    }
    void AddColumn(Type type, string name) {
        m_innerTable.Columns.Add(type, name);
    }
```

With a factory method you can return the respective adapter:

```
public static class MagicFactory {
    public static IMagic GetMagic(bool useNoSql) {
        if (useNoSql) {
            return new NoSqlMagic();
        }
        else {
            return new SqlMagic();
        }
    }
}
```

Your core code can be kept clean by only using the abstractions returned by the factory:

```
public class DoDatabaseStuff() {
    private IMagic _magic
    public DoDatabaseStuff(bool useNoSql) {
       _magic = MagicFactory.GetMagic(useNoSql);
       ITable myTable = _magic.CreateTable("CustomerTable");
       myTable.AddColumn(typeof(int), "ID");
       myTable.AddColumn(typeof(string), "Name");
   }
}
```

An added advantage is that you are also ready for any future changes, for example yet another updated external library that is not compatible to the previous ones. You can easily support these new functionalities without changing your core code.